# How do I spin these 2 processes in threads?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a method which loads data from 2 regions. Currently its processes region1 and then processes region 2. So its single thread. I would need to do them so its simultaneous. Here is the curent code. Please advice what do I need to do.

### enter code here

```
public override object RProcess()            
{            
      string queueName = Config.AppSettings["MQSIInboundQueueName"];

        string Region1 = Config.AppSettings["Region1"];
        string Region2 = Config.AppSettings["Region2"];

        string returnMessage = string.Empty;
        if (Region1.Trim().Length > 0)
        {                
            returnMessage = ProcessMessage(string.Format(queueName, Region1));
            Logger.Log(returnMessage);
        }

        if (Region2.Trim().Length > 0)
        {
            returnMessage = ProcessMessage(string.Format(queueName, Region2));
            Logger.Log(returnMessage);
        }

        return null;
    }
```

--

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to @Drew Marsh answer here if you are using older version of .net, you can invoke every operation in new thread, using `Thread` class or `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem`

```
//example using Thread class
new Thread(() =>
{
    if (Region1.Trim().Length > 0)
    {                
        returnMessage = ProcessMessage(string.Format(queueName, Region1));
        Logger.Log(returnMessage);
    }
}) { IsBackground = true }.Start();

//example using ThreadPool
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback((_) =>
{
    if (Region2.Trim().Length > 0)
    {
        returnMessage = ProcessMessage(string.Format(queueName, Region2));
        Logger.Log(returnMessage);
    }
}));
```

Anyway if you are updating `Region1` or `Region2` form any other place in the application, then you should consider using synchronization mechanism to access them here such as `lock`..

Comment: Thanks for the reply Jalal. I saw only one place the regions are used: Its like below. Do I need to use the lock here?          string Region1 = Config.AppSettings["region1"]; string Region2 = Config.AppSettings["Region2"]; OutputQueue = mqQMgr.AccessQueue(string.Format(Config.AppSettings["MQSIInboundQueueName"],shawRegion1), InOpenOptions);

Comment: @Ree: if you are only using the regions here then I think you are safe without locking, however you have to be sure that you are not updating any shared variable or data in the `ProcessMessage` method then, if you are not updating any shared data or variables then you don't have to use `lock` or other synchronization mechanism here.

Comment: @Ree: looking to your updated code in the comment: I don't know what is the code in `mqQMgr.AccessQueue` it really depend on it.

Comment: That code in the comment can be ignored. I found that in a test project file. So we are not updating the regions anywhere else other than in the  RProcess()  method.

Comment: Looks like the Processmethod is updating shared data and variables. Where do I need to use the lock and synchronization? Thanks

Comment: @Jalal.. I got what you are saying. I'm trying the code out. I'll update

Comment: I don't know where you should lock exactly because I didn't sow the implementation. however in general you should lock before interacting with the shared data and variables...

Comment: Can I add multiple locks in the ProcessMessage method at different code blocks like this?                                             lock(this)  { doing something } ... ... ... lock (this) { servervarible = "a" } ... .... etc

Comment: You can, but you shouldn't do `lock (this)` instead declare some object at class level and lock at it like: `lock (_mySyncLocker)`.

Comment: In the above code, instead of putting the first thread into a Background thread, can we put both into a foreground thread? How do I accomplish that?

Comment: Background thread is typical of Foreground thread, the only difference is that if you try to terminate your application, the foreground threads will prevents your application from closing until they finishes there work, where the background thread will not prevents your application from closing, so if the user closes the application they will automatically terminated. to your question: to run your thread as a foreground thread use the first example in the answer without specifying the `IsBackground` property, or specify it to false, note that when using `ThreadPool`, it will be background.

Comment: @ Jalal. Thank you. I used the second example. What that did was its multithreading each of the process. For example region 1 processes with multiple threads and when it is finished region 2 processes next with multiple threads. Actually it should do multiple channels that will process both regions at the same time. May be the 1st example will work in this scenario. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: The both examples work the same, if you start both process like `ThreadPool.Queue(..Region1); then ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(..Region2);` both will start parallel working, the first will not block until finishes, so execution will continue to the second one and it will started too, however if you have further questions, I suggest you to Ask them in a new post "using `Ask Question..`"

Comment: @ Jalal. Thanks. So I use the second example except I do this for 1st region code - ThreadPool.Queue(new WaitCallback((_) => { if (Region2.Trim().Length > 0) { returnMessage = ProcessMessage(string.Format(queueName, Region2)); Logger.Log(returnMessage); } })); ------------- But I am not use or get ThreadPool.Queue.

Comment: What if I add New Thread (region 1) and Threadpool (region2) ?

Comment: Generally speaking, each time you do `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` you are starting a new thread in a pool so it is equals to `new Thread(..).Start()` but the last one is not in application intern thread pool, so either use `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` for both, or `new Thread...` for both.

Answer (score 5):

Wow, loaded question. I have to make a couple assumptions with my answer here:

1. You're using .NET 4.0
2. The ProcessMessage method does not access any non-protected, shared state that would be impacted by multiple threads calling into it concurrently.
3. Logger.Log also does not access any non-protected, shared state that would be impacted by multiple threads calling into it concurrently.

With that, [Parallel::Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992634.aspx) is your friend:

```
Parallel.Invoke(
    () =>
    {
       string region1 = Config.AppSettings["Region1"];

       if(region1.Trim().Length > 0)
       {
            string region1ReturnMessage = ProcessMessage(string.Format(queueName, region1));
            Logger.Log(region1ReturnMessage);
       }
    },
    () =>
    {
       string region2 = Config.AppSettings["Region2"];

       if(region2.Trim().Length > 0)
       {
            string region2ReturnMessage = ProcessMessage(string.Format(queueName, region2));
            Logger.Log(region2ReturnMessage);
       }
    });
```

Also, something else to consider, is that if it's a common occurrence to not actually call ProcessMessage for a particular region because of those checks, then it could make sense to do those checks up front on the main thread and not always dispatch the multiple calls. In that case you would need to drop down into pure TPL task management code and dynamically allocate only the number of tasks you need. I would bother only do this if this code is going to be executed under load inside of some kind of service process itself. Otherwise this is a premature optimization. If you'd like to see what the raw TPL approach would look like, just let me know in a comment and I will provide an example.

Comment: I think you need to put the `if()`s inside the lambdas.

Comment: @Henk Holterman - Sure, good call. Updated the example to include all the logic so it was clearer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, I am using .Net 4.0. I don't think ProcessMessage and Logger.log accesses any non protected data. But I will further investigate it. The code is in a service. The ProcessMessage checks if the system is down and some other stuff.   I am not able to get using System.Threading.Tasks to use the Parallel.Invoke.

Comment: I am not able to get using System.Threading.Tasks to use the Parallel.Invoke.  Do I need to add any reference?

Comment: Nope, these classes live in mscorlib. Double check to make sure your project is set to use ".NET Framework 4".

Comment: Dang! this particular project is using version 3.5

Comment: Can you upgrade? If not I would just use ThreadPool::QueueUserWorkItem as Jalal suggested in the other answer.